# When I call a procedure.... how can I check for duplicate values in a column?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Im stuck on a SQL assignment... I created this procedure

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_glaccount
(
  account_number_param general_ledger_accounts.account_number%TYPE,
  account_description_param general_ledger_accounts.account_description%TYPE
)
AS 
BEGIN   
  INSERT INTO general_ledger_accounts
  VALUES (account_number_param, account_description_param);          
END;
/
```

I need to call the procedure and check for duplicate account numbers. If there is a duplicate then I would need output one message. I've been trying different things but nothing seems to work.

I would appreciate any help or some advice thanks

Comment: you mean to say that your want to insert_glaccount procedure and after execution of it you want to display the message that record insert into the table are duplicate or not .

Comment: I meant after execution. I solved it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
declare
  total_row number;
begin
  select count(*)
  into   total_row 
  from   general_ledger_accounts
  where conditions whatever you want


  if total_row then
    ...
  else
    ...
  end if;
```